# Diferent window size between Eclipse and Processing

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, processing

I am developing a Processing app. Last yesterday I migrated that code to eclipse in a view to export it to a jar file (I know processing provides that option but I need to use eclipse).

The thing is that everything seemed to work ok except for one thing: the screen size. Although I used the same size (1000 px by 600 px), it was shown bigger in the eclipse code. Here's an image:[image]

Why is that, how can I fix it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not familiar with your project, are you importing `PApplet` into a java program or is this somehow pure Processing but in an eclipse IDE?

Comment: I am importing the core.jar library and importing PApplet.

Comment: Do you have a `draw()` method in your `PApplet`?

Comment: yep, I use settings() just for the size, setup() and draw()

Comment: Did you, at any moment, change the pixel density?

Comment: As far as I know, never, but if i had, shouldn't the processing window also get bigger?

Comment: It's probably something else, but the idea of pixel density is that the screen doesn't get bigger, only more defined. Problem may arise if the DPI is applied differently by Processing or the other IDE. I'm stumped so far, but I'll keep thinking.

Comment: Which renderer are you using?

Comment: I think I use the default, I mean in size just the width and height, not P3D or something else. If that's what you're asking for.

Comment: It was exactly what I was about. Now, please check if Windows is scaling your stuff. Check through `Display settings --> Scale and layout`. [Here's an image](https://imgur.com/a/H5rHX7m). I right click on my desktop to get to Display settings. (I know my settings are weird, my setup is kinda weird too)